# How do I search questions that are closed as off-topic?

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

According to "Advanced Search Tips", I can search questions that are closed with `closed:yes`. But I want to search questions that are closed as **off-topic**. (not primarily opinion based, too broad or unclear)

So, How do I search questions that are closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), there is no such option. You can narrow down it a little by searching for `closed:yes duplicate:no`, this will at least exclude the duplicates (this will keep 'unclear' and 'too broad').

The best option you have is using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), which is better capable of [searching on close reasons](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/309999/all-questions-closed-as-off-topic).

Comment: Sounds helpful ; when I tried it for Hinduism.SE, I found all of-topic question but still there is some noise of other type exist

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) tool to query. [This query shows the IDs of the off-topic reasons that would interest you](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/435451).

Note that some of these are deprecated, and there aren't *very* many questions still showing them that are still visible on the site.

But, you should be able to fish out the information you need without a lot of work.